# Euclidean Space Sets.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

im looking to achieve a formal/concrete understand as to why this is true.

Prove that if Both $S_{1},S_{2}\subset \mathbb {R^{n}}$ and $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ are both open or both closed then $S_{1} \cup S_{2}$ and $S_{1} \cap S_{2}$ are both open or closed respectfully.

Informally this is obvious but as with many things in math writing down why something (thats obvious) is true can be very difficult.

When both $S_{1},S_{2}$ are open i can make a bit of an argument.

Since $S_{1}$ is open $\forall x \in S_{1} \exists B(r_{1},x)$ such that $r_{1}\in \mathbb{R} $

likewise for $S_{2}$, $\forall y \in S_{2} \exists B(r_{2},y)$ such that $r_{2}\in \mathbb{R} $

ie. Everything is an interior point of $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$

Somehow this should give me a strong argument that $\forall z \in S_{1} \cup S_{2}$

$ \exists B(r_{3},z)$ such that $r_{3} \in \mathbb{R}$

This certainly isn't compelling for one i have difficulty implying that $r <\infty$ in a satisfying manner as well there is no direct path to get a handle on the size of $r_{3}$ 
What i mean is i cannot describe $r_{3}$ in terms of $r_{1}$ and $r_{2}$ without cases and the case where $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ are mutually disjoint makes it feel more compelling to approach the problem in a different way altogether.  (though i can think of ways it will make the radius larger then needed which seems just sloppy)

Don't even get me started on the closed sets... I would rather not borrow from theorems i would like to see why directly that this idea is true if it all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to prove that $S_1\cup S_2$ is open, as you said we have to prove that every point is an interior point. Let $z\in S_1\cup S_2$. Then $z$ is in either $S_1$ or $S_2$. Say (without loss of generality) that $z\in S_1$. Then there exists an $r$ so that $B(r,z)\subset S_1$ because $S_1$ is open. Note that the same ball shows that $B(r,z)\subset S_1\cup S_2$, so indeed $z$ is interior.

To prove that $S_1\cap S_2$ is open, let $z\in S_1\cap S_2$, so we have htat $z\in S_1$ and $z\in S_2$. Thus, there are $_1$ and $r_2$ so that: $B(z,r_1)\subset S_1$, and $B(z,r_2)\subset S_2$. Take the minimum of $r_1$ and $r_2$. Say without loss of generality its $r_1$. Then we have that $B(z,r_1)\subset B(z,r_2)$, so we have that $B(z,r_1)\subset S_2$ as well, and so it is in the intersection. $B(z,r_1)\subset S_1\cap S_2$.

For the closed statements you can use De Morgan rules.

Comment: That very clever, exactly what i wanted to say but surprisingly difficult to get out. Thank you.